# Remove entire object directory tree using AWS-SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the aws-sdk, and I'm trying to delete an object with the `#delete_object` method, for example:

`s3.delete_object(bucket: ENV["AWS_BUCKET"]), key: "images/123/myimage.png")`)

How can I delete the route (that's "images/123") instead of only the .png file? I don't want empty "folders". I've tested adding only the first part of the route (`s3.delete_object(bucket: ENV["AWS_BUCKET"]), key: "images/")`) in the key parameter but doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The folder will auto delete when it's empty.

So if you delete your file and refresh the root folder, you will see that it's gone ! Aws-Magic =)