# aws-sdk delete_object deletes entire bucket contents?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Learning the ropes of AWS S3 and the sdk.  Trying to use in in my Rails app via the aws-sdk gem.  I was following this post:

[Remove entire object directory tree using AWS-SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343958/remove-entire-object-directory-tree-using-aws-sdk)

Luckily for me that I was playing around in my staging bucket.  I created a folder `test` and uploaded an `example.jpg` image.  From the rails console I ran (note the lack of {} brackets):

```
s3.delete_object(bucket: 'mystagingbucket', key: '/test/example.jpg')
=> #<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=true, version_id=nil, request_charged=nil>
```

then I go back into the web console to find my entire bucket empty.  All my previously uploaded files, static assets, etc. all gone.

So I realize that I should turn versioning on and try this again to duplicate the issue.  After some Googling I see the docs show the {} brackets.

Now I get:

```
s3.delete_object({bucket: 'mystagingbucket', key: '/test/example.jpg'})
=> #<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=true, version_id="blohAaXlnG2.RERnj_JT3zvQmAr8io48", request_charged=nil>
```

except that nothing happens and the file is not deleted.  I have done some more Googling and I now see that it can take up to a few hours to see your files actually deleted so I will check back on the recent delete issues.

As for the bucket contents getting erased am I missing something here?

Comment: That code would not have deleted your entire bucket contents. There has to be something else going on to have caused that. Also it takes a few seconds at most, not hours for an item to actually be deleted in S3. If you found something stating hours it was probably talking about CloudFront cache in front of an S3 bucket.

Comment: Yes - something else has to be going on but I am at a loss to figure it out now.  As for my deleting of files I have the leading `/` in there which was the problem.  I am not sure why some sort of error is thrown when you try to delete an object that does not exist.